# Javascript library/framework/widget to allow user to move and resize divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am looking at creating a page that the user can move around as they please...very similar to [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig). But in addition, ideally, I want the user to be able to resize the components.

I've done quite a bit with jQuery in the past am not against the idea of using that, seeing as it already has the draggable and resizable options, though, there's still a fair amount of work involved.

So, before I start - I've done some googling with no success - is there some kind of widget out there that already does this that's available for free commercial use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) if you've done quite a bit with jQuery:

- [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)
- [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)
- [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)